# infinite scrolling with custom view in Android

Tags: android, view, calendar, scroll, custom-draw

I'am programming a calendar application which shows the appointments in a week-oriented view.

I implemented the graphics by custom drawing in onDraw() of a View.

The graphics contains fixed parts (time bar) and calendar relative parts (days, appointments).

What is the best way to implement a horizontal scroll through the calendar?

I can't use the ScrollView because I have no fixed maximum width since the user should be able to scroll in the past and in the future "*unlimited*".

I thought to draw the relative parts in an image which contains 2 days more as the week view requires (one left one right) and draw the bitmap with the calculated offset at the Views Canvas.

As soon the offset exceeds one day I had than to redraw the bitmap.

Does anybody know a more elegant solution?

Regards Andreas

Comment: did you get a better solution for this?